# how can I display a last modified time on ms access form

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access (2010) form with a bunch of linked tabled to XLSX files (both stored locally). On the main form is a built in auto update feature which essentially copies any new versions of the front end and XLSX files from a central server locally (auto generated daily). Is it possible to add the date modified/last write time stamp from the local XLSX file on the main form?

I've tried:

1. `="Last Modified: " & DLookUp("[DateUpdate]","MSysObjects","[Name] = '***tablename***'")` as a control source however this doesn't give the data i need.
2. I can get the desired result in powershell by the command `(Get-ItemProperty -Path $source).LastWriteTime.tostring("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm")` ,though I have no idea how I can tie in the result into an access form. Any ideas?

Noteworthy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724926%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (C++ is foreign to me and not even sure it applies to this question)

Answer (score 0):

[FileDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264782%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> returns a Variant (Date) that indicates the date and time when a file
>   was created or last modified.

```
Dim dtLast As Date
dtLast = FileDateTime("F:\Documents and Settings\student\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Debug.Print dtLast      '29/06/2013 19:46:03
```

You can then use `Format` to display the value appropriately, and perhaps set it as the `Caption` of a `Label`.

```
Debug.Print Format(dtLast, "ddd dd mmm")    'Sat 29 Jun
```

If you want this information for an Access Table then:

```
    Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object

    Set dbs = Application.CurrentData
    Set obj = dbs.AllTables("tblStaff")
    Debug.Print obj.Name; " "; obj.DateModified; " "; obj.DateCreated
    'tblStaff 16/04/2013 14:50:46  28/02/2010 19:46:56
```

Comment: Thanks Andy,

Where do I put the code? In the control source / event builder or code builder within 'on event'? I need the result to be displayed on an access form. ty

Dim dtLast As Date
dtLast = FileDateTime("F:\Documents and Settings\student\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Debug.Print dtLast      '29/06/2013 19:46:03

Comment: I managed to get this working by adding in a wrapper to the form code:

Public Function myFileDateTime(ByVal f As String)
    myFileDateTime = FileDateTime(f)
End Function

Then changed my expression to:
=myFileDateTime("s:\apps\AQMD\data\survey_results.csv").